# Sorting List<Object[]>

Tags: java, sorting, collections, testng

I have a list of Object array.

```
List<Object[]> lFiles = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
```

and I want to sort this list and I am not sure what is the best way to achieve it. I have tried `Comparator` but I am not getting how to do this. I am using this technique so I can pass the Iterator to use as dataProvider in testNG.

Can anyone tell if there any other good way of returning list to use as a data provider in testNG.

Complete Method

```
@DataProvider( name = "gFile" )
    //generated
    public static Iterator<Object[]> getGenerated()
    {
        List<Object[]> lFiles = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
        listf( path + "generated/",
               lFiles );
         Collections.sort( lFiles,
                          new Comparator<Object>()
                          {

                              public int compare( Object o1,
                                      Object o2 )
                              {
                                  return compare( o1.toString(),
                                                  o2.toString() );
                              }
                          } );
        return lFiles.iterator();
    }

public static void listf( String directoryName,
            List<Object[]> lFiles )
    {
        File directory = new File( directoryName );

        // get all the files from a directory
        File[] fList = directory.listFiles();

        for( File file : fList )
        {
            if( file.isFile() )
            {
                if( file.getName().endsWith( ".java" ) )
                    lFiles.add( new Object[] { file.getName() } );
            }
            else if( file.isDirectory() )
            {
                listf( file.getAbsolutePath(),
                       lFiles );
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: First, you have to decide what “sorted” means.  Specifically, you need to decide how the order is determined.  Why should one Object[] come before or after another Object[]?

Comment: basically it is list of files(names), so I want to sort them lexicographically @VGR

Comment: Okay, so each Object[] contains only Strings.  Do you only care about the first String in each array?

Comment: yes, I have edited the question have a look at this @V

Comment: Please update your question to make it clear what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I have updated @Thorvason

Comment: Why are you creating arrays of length 1?  Why not just make `lFiles` be of type `List<File>` or `List<String>`?

Comment: The annotated method can only return an Object[][] (or iterator to List<Object[]>) where each Object[] can be assigned the parameter list of the test method, in testNg. @VGR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to sort using `Comparator` you could do something like below code.

```
static void test () {
    List<Object[]> lFiles = new ArrayList<>();

    Collections.sort(lFiles , new Comparator<Object[]>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Object[] o1, Object[] o2) {
            // Write the logic how two array will compare. 
            return 0;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This is not working, I am getting error when I am using new Comparator<Object[]>{...}